# How to deploy Oracle Jet application to Nginx?

Tags: nginx, oracle-jet

I have an O-jet application and need to deploy it to Nginx.

I have installed Nginx in windows and have it working successfully.

From my understanding, I just need to modify the nginx.conf file and re-load the config file, the application will be available in the specified url.

How to change the nginx.conf since I want to deploy it to specified http://host:port?

Answer (score 0):

Simply copy your OJET project into nginx's web root.

OJET is a JS toolkit, not a web application, so usually, your project files are static content.